# How can i solve this?

Tags: greedy

Given an undirected weighted graph G = (V,E). Each vertex represents a city and the weight of an edge connected a and b is the number of years that it will take to finish building a high speed route between city a and city b. Describe an algorithm that will find the least number of years before one can travel between any two cities in the graph.
The routes are being built simultaneously, so that if we have three cities a, b and c and an edge between a and b with weight 1, another edge between b and c with weight 2, then the output should be 2.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm

Comment: would simply using prim's or kruskal's to find a minimum spanning tree, then return the largest weight of all the edges in the mst work? if so, how would you go about proving the algorithm's correctness?

Comment: For Kruskal, proving is quite simple, since you are always consider the smallest edge first when adding. I am not that sure about Prim, but it is probably provable.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question to me.

Answer (score 1):

The comment above is pointing you the right answer, in my opinion this sounds like a classic Prim's algorithm problem. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)

Comment: How is that? can you be more specific please? for instance, would simply using prim's to find a minimum spanning tree, then return the largest weight of all the edges in the mst work? if so, how would you go about proving the algorithm's correctness?

Comment: @AdenDong I would do it just like you said. If the construction of the railways are all taking place simultaneously, then the minimum spanning tree will mathematically give you the optimum routes that should be build to connect all the nodes in the network. The longest arc between two vertices in your path between A and B should be how much you would have to wait to travel.